# aiohttp: how-to retrieve the data (body) in aiohttp server from requests.get

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x, aiohttp

Could you please advise on the following?

On the `localhost:8900` there is aiohttp server running

When I do a request like (using the python2 module requests) from python

```
requests.get("http://127.0.01:8900/api/bgp/show-route",
             data={'topo':"switzerland",
                   'pop':"zrh",
                   'prefix':"1.1.1.1/32"})
```

And there is a route defined in the aiohttp server

```
app.router.add_route("GET", "/api/bgp/show-route", api_bgp_show_route)
```

which is being handled like

```
def api_bgp_show_route(request):
    pass
```

The question is: how do I retrieve on server-side the data part of the request? meaning `{'topo':"switzerland", 'pop':"zrh", 'prefix':"1.1.1.1/32"}`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

ahh the `data` part is accessed like that

```
await request.json()
```

You can find this in official [aiohttp docs](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Request.json)

Comment: await is the key here and the co-routine has to be a async/await request. But aiohttp library supports synchronous also. This confuses the developers in this regard. I hope, aiohttp-server module supports only async/await methods in order to retrieve the posted content from the HTTP Body. Kindly correct me if there is any way of rendering the Posted Content.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the format you want the data to be.

To get a string:

```
request.text()
```

To get bytes:

```
request.read()
```

To get a JSON dict (Attention, throws a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError if the data is malformatted!):

```
request.json()
```

Answer (score 6):

you can access POST request body data using

```
if request.body_exists:
        print(await request.read())
```